# Chrome use SVGs sometimes don't show up

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, svg

I am currently using "external" SVGs and for some unknown reason they sometimes won't render in Google Chrome. It happens every other refresh, but sometimes they all show up.

I've Googled this extensively and here's what I have tried so far:

- Disabled HTML5 mode
- Removed base href="/"
- Used absolute URLs for the map.svg
- Updated Google Chrome
- Remove svg4everybody

I can't reproduce it on my local environment, only when I deploy it on an external server which makes it extremely frustrating to debug. I'm completely out of ideas.

map.svg

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <symbol id="icon-chevron-left" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <title>chevron-left</title>
        <path d="M10.413 12l5.294-5.294c0.387-0.387 0.387-1.025 0-1.413s-1.025-0.387-1.413 0l-6 6c-0.387 0.387-0.387 1.025 0 1.413l6 6c0.194 0.194 0.45 0.294 0.706 0.294s0.513-0.1 0.706-0.294c0.387-0.387 0.387-1.025 0-1.413l-5.294-5.294z"/>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

HTML reference

```
<svg class="icon">
    <use xlink:href="static/map.svg#icon-chevron-left"></use>
</svg>
```

It only happens in Chrome and it's sporadic, which makes it very hard to debug. I'm using AngularJS 1.6.6 being served by Tomcat 8.5. Currently my chrome version is 61.0.3163.100

I understand this is a very random question with no minimal test case but I'm hoping someone went through this already and can give me a direction to pursue.